# limit pages shown in pagination php script

Tags: php

I have 100+ records in my database so i am using pagination but it prints page number for every page like 1,2,3,5 and so on how to limit the number shown in pagination.

Here is my code:

```
$row_offer2=mysqli_num_rows($sql_result2);
$total=ceil($row_offer2/$num_rec);

echo "<div class='col-md-12' style='margin:0 auto;text-align:center;'><ul 
class='pagination '>";
 echo "<li id='1' class='pag'>".'|<'."</li>"; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++) { 
echo "<li id=".$i." class='pag'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
}; 
echo "<li id=".$total." class='pag'>".'>|'."</a></li> "; // Goto last page
echo "</ul></div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Show pagination for current page +- x pages (x should be something like 2-3) and show the first and last page.

```
$currentPage = 6;

function getPages($cp, $max, $offset) {
    $pages = [];
    $pages[] = 1;
    $min = ($cp - $offset) > 1 ? $cp - $offset : 1;
    $lim = ($cp + $offset) < $max ? $cp + $offset : $max;
    for ($i = $min; $i < $lim; $i++) {
        $pages[] = $i;
    }
    $pages[] = $max;

    return array_unique($pages);
}

var_dump(getPages($currentPage, 20, 3));
```

then you can simply loop with foreach through array you receive from this function and display your LIs

Answer (score 0):

Control your loop with number you want to show. If you want to show 3 pages in pagination just do this.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) { 
    echo "<li id=".$i." class='pag'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
};
```

Comment: then how to get on page 4,5,6 etc